# Call to a member function test1() on a non-object

Tags: php, class, member-functions

I'm still pretty new to php and all but I've been trying to lookup(if it's even possible) to call from a child class to a parent function which executes a different child's function. I've read that child classes are not aware of each other but I thought the parent class might be.

I have indeed been searching for a few hours but I have yet to find something that I thought would help.

The following will output:

```
::dad Class initiated::
::daughter Class initiated::
::son Class initiated::

Call to a member function test1() on a non-object in ....  on line 15
```

Code:

```
class dad {  

    function dad() 
    { 
        echo '::'.get_class($this).' Class initiated::<br>';
        $this -> daughter = new daughter();
        $this -> son = new son();
    }

    public function afunction($string) {

        return $this->son->test1($string);

    }

}

class daughter extends dad {

    function daughter() {
    echo '::'.get_class($this).' Class initiated::<br>';

    }

    public function test() {

        parent::afunction("test");

    }

}

class son extends dad {

    function son() {
    echo '::'.get_class($this).' Class initiated::<br>';

    }

    public function test1($string) {

        echo $string;

    }

}


$dad = new dad(); 
$dad->daughter->test();
```

Any/all help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: `function dad` should be a contructor? Then use `__construct`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to call function of a child class from parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: [PHP: How to call function of a child class from parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class)

In general, calling a child classes method they way you are trying to isn't correct. Child classes are designed to extend an existing (fully functional in most cases) class, it shouldn't rely on a child existing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use constructors like dad() or similiar user magic function __construct() instead. I am pretty sure that You don't have visible field daughter in dad class. You have to define that.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: `dad`,`daughter` and `son` are separate objects, calling function form `parent` works only inside one object. In your example `daughter` does not know that is bound to the `dad` object, only it inherits properties and methods from it. To make it work, you should pass parent object to the children to make them aware of their parents, and call functions on this parent object:

```
class dad {  
    function dad(){ 
        echo '::'.get_class($this).' Class initiated::<br>';
        $this -> daughter = new daughter($this);
        $this -> son = new son($this);
    }

    public function afunction($string){
       return $this->son->test1($string);
    }
}

class daughter extends dad {
    function daughter($father) {
        $this->father = $father;
        echo '::'.get_class($this).' Class initiated::<br>';
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->father->afunction("test");
    }
}

class son extends dad {
    function son($father) {
        $this->father = $father;
        echo '::'.get_class($this).' Class initiated::<br>';
    }

    public function test1($string) {
        echo $string;
    }
}

$dad = new dad(); 
$dad->daughter->test();
```

Comment: Why did you suggest a php4 convention of naming the constructor after the class? Should use `__construct`.

Comment: I didn't suggest, just copied OP code with only necessary changes to make it easier to understand.