# Calling an Abstract method from parent abstract class

Tags: php, oop, class, abstract

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class), I tried the chosen answer myself!
So basically what I wrote was `

```
abstract class person
{

  function __construct()
  {
    // some code here
  }

  function myfunc()
  {
    $this->test();
  }

  abstract function test();
}

class employee extends person
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function test()
  {
    echo "So you managed to call me !!";
  }

}


$employee = new employee();
$employee->myfunc();`
```

When I run this script, I got an usual error 
**Fatal error:** Using $this when not in object context on line 7.

So, how do I call an Abstract from the Parent Class?

- EDIT

The real thing which I am trying to do is create a DatabaseObject class which holds all the common methods of different database objects and make classes extend it.

```
abstract class DatabaseObject {
   abstract protected function getTableName();

   public static function find_by_id($id = 0){
        global $database;
        $class = get_called_class();

        $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ". $this->getTableName() ." WHERE _id = {$id} LIMIT 1");
        echo $result_array . "<br />";
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
    }

    public static function find_by_sql($sql=""){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)){
            $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $object_array;
    }
   }
}
```

So this is some part of my DatabaseObject Class. My User class is as follows

```
class User extends DatabaseObject {
    protected static $table_name = "users";

    protected function getTableName(){
        global $table_name;
        return $table_name;
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I do

```
$user = new User();
$user->findById(1);
```

I get the error Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context 
on the line which points to

```
$this->getTableName();
```

I hope this might help in clearing up some stuff. Is there any way I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: The error is not unusual, especially not when you get it. It's predictable and reproduceable. -- Your code looks OK by the way (you could remove the fish's constructor function if it's only job is to call the parents constructor).

Comment: @Shobhit, is this your final code?

Comment: @hakre  : This is only an example he is showing. what he wants is to call that abstract method in the function.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque This is just an example of what I am trying to do. All I want is to call an Abstract method From the class itself!

Comment: I added the real purpose and the real code I am trying out. Hope this helps!

Comment: And btw, please read this book: http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa

Comment: Ok, so now I have posted the exact code. I hope now you could help.

Comment: My mistake was that I forgot to add $this-> before the test() call but this question made me realize it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example works just fine, I don't understand your issue [Demo](http://codepad.org/ip0ERfwR).

So the code you've shared is not the code you talk about with the error .

Comment: @Shobhit: Even with your update, this makes no sense. The error pops up if you call some function **statically** which you don't do. Check your code, there is something hidden.

Comment: I am pulling in the static variable using global into a function and then returning the value of table name. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Could this be because I am using static finction? Check my question again!

Comment: Yes, that can cause that. Do not use static methods, you normally don't need them. Same for the global variable you make use of. As written, check the book I've linked above in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can not call the variable as if it were a member of the class, since you declared it static. Calls to static variables looks the same as when you call static functions, use the :: operator.

```
class User extends DatabaseObject {
    protected static $table_name = "users";

    protected function getTableName(){
        return self::$table_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used global to pull in the table_name. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Interesting... that might have caused the error, will look into it... But please dont use globals in this case.

Comment: No, the use of globals have nothing to do with the error. As the error message says: you can not use $this when reffering to a static variable. Either remove the keyword static, or use self::$table_name

Comment: What error message are you getting. The code I posted works, the error must come from somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access the abstract function inside the same abstract class.

What ever your needs are, you have to call that method in sub class only, abstract super class will not call the sub class function.

**EDIT:**

Because the function dosent exists in that class.

Comment: Could you suggest me what could I do then? I've edited the question to include my requirements and real code.

Comment: This is not the case when it comes to PHP, you do have access to abstract functions within the same class.

Comment: @vic : Yeep, just executed the program. well thanks for clarifying.:)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you can not call the abstract function within the same class. You are calling test(); in side myfunc() which is not allowed by oops.

Comment: Could you suggest me what could I do then? I've edited the question to include my requirements and real code.