# php - Access parent class array in child class

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, multidimensional-array

```
class Settings {
    public $constants = [
        'database' => [
            'APP_DB_HOST'       =>  'localhost'
        ],
    ];
}
class Constants extends Settings {
    public $database = [
        'APP_DB_HOST'       =>  $settings->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST'], // not working
    ];
}
```

I need to access parent class array values in child class. but this `$settings->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST']` is not working for some reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class. Refer in this one. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Referring to a declared `$variable` as a `$constant` doesn't make it a "constant" -- it is still a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution

```
<?php

class Settings {
    public $constants = [
        'database' => [
            'APP_DB_HOST'       =>  'localhost'
        ],
    ];
}
class Constants extends Settings {
    public $database;
    public function __construct(){
        $database = [
            'APP_DB_HOST'       =>  $this->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST'], // working
        ];
    }
}

print_r(new Constants());
```

outputs:

```
Constants Object
(
    [database] => 
    [constants] => Array
        (
            [database] => Array
                (
                    [APP_DB_HOST] => localhost
                )

        )

)
```

as per your comment,
if you want to do it in other class function, you can do that as well.

```
class Constants extends Settings {
    public $database;
    public function useParentHost(){
        $this->database = [
        'APP_DB_HOST'       =>  $this->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST'], // working
    ];
    return $this->database;
    }
}
```

and then

```
$test = new Constants();
print_r($test->useParentHost());
```

you have to declare some function to use `$this`, without/outside the `function` this will cause an error.

Comment: thanks. is this the only way to put array inside constructor?

Comment: second approach is more cleaner, and yields more clean output, Thank to @Dan

Comment: can you please tell one more thing. outside the the class i did `$constants  = new Constants();` and  `echo $constants->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST'];` it is working but not `$constants->database['APP_DB_HOST'];`why is it?

Comment: if you use second approach, you can get `localhost` by doing this
`$test = new Constants();
$constants = ($test->useParentHost());
echo $constants['APP_DB_HOST'];`

Comment: i tried this but it is showing empty. i am looking to find the problem.

Comment: in your case, what you're doing is: you're creating an object, `$constants = new Constants();` and now `$constansts` is pointing toward `array $database`, so to access it you'll have to do is ` $constants->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST'];` it means, your `object` is pointing to `array key`

Comment: using  arrays in construct was referring to the parent class arrays and not child class. but using the a new function cause it to use the child class arrays. this is what i got after experimenting

Answer (score 0):

The variable $settings does not exist, perhaps you mean $this?

```
$this->constants['database']['APP_DB_HOST'];
```

Enjoy.

Comment: directly using `$this` inside a `class` outside of `function` will cause an error

Comment: Ahh yeas, nice spot! Didn't notice he was trying to initialise a property. However wouldn't the correct syntax for your answer be $this->database = $this->constants[X]?

Comment: yes, but if we use `$this->database`, it yields output like this
`Constants Object ( [database] => Array ( [APP_DB_HOST] => localhost ) [constants] => Array ( [database] => Array ( [APP_DB_HOST] => localhost ) ) )`