# Call Child Method in Main Class

Tags: php

I wanna call a Child Method in Main Class without declare new child();

```
class main {
    function __construct() {

    }
    public function test() {

    }
 }

class child extends main {
    function __construct() {

    }
    function childmethod() {
        return "test";
    }
}

$main = new main();
$main->childmethod();
```

best wishes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to call function of a child class from parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make class as `abstract` and declare the method you want to call from child class as `abstract`.

```
abstract class main {
    function __construct() {

    }
    public function test() {
          return "test";
    }

  abstract function childmethod();
 }

class child extends main {
    function __construct() {

    }
    function childmethod() {
        return "childmethod";
    }
}

$main = new child();
echo $main->childmethod();// echoes childmethod
echo $main->test();// echoes test
```

Comment: Its `extends`, not `extend` as @Uchiha has said with the `Parse error: ...`

Comment: I just copied from OP's question. Thank you:)

Comment: This won't work. You need to instantiate a `new child()` instead of `new main()`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're asking for, you cannot do it and it's a mistake in the project idea.
If you need to call a child method in the parent, it means the method should go in the parent.

There's no way to call a method of an object without instantiate the object, unless you create a static method

Comment: i have a json api created.
Now i wanna split this into peaces per modal / area.
for example:
API 
- Refs
- News
- bla

thats why i have the question.

Comment: I understand. But when you discover that a method is necessary in the parent, the best way to do it, is move the method in the parent