# how to use method of main class from the extended class and avoiding constructor loop

Tags: php

```
class a
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $x = new b();
        $x->myFunction();
    }
}
class b extends a
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        echo 'Here is myFunction';
    }
}
$a = new a();
```

now i want to know how to access function myFunction of class b from class  a and avoid the infinity loop.

Comment: From my understanding, when a class is extended, it's constructor is not called

Comment: You have to implement an empty `__construct` method in your class `b`.

Comment: you are trying to access child class methods in parent class.

Comment: Andreas Scheibleger it doesn't work

Comment: If you want to access methods from the child class in its parent, then you should consider using abstract classes. This link should be of great help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class

Comment: non of your suggestions worked

Comment: ...avoid WHAT? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but how about removing `$x = new b();` and just calling `$this->myFunction();`?

Comment: but it is neecessary to call the function from a class

Comment: if u tried my code you will gett unlimited loop and error after 256 times

Comment: It's molto rumore per nulla. Just an example of bad design. Your example must stuck in recursion, it is written like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, what you want to do is [Abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) the parent class. Thus allowing you to call children classes from it's parent.

As the comment suggested too, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1944827/2518525) has a range of examples of how you could achieve your task as you see below.

```
abstract class a {

    function __construct() {
        $this->myFunction();
    }
}

class b extends a {

    function myFunction() {
         echo 'im from class b, sweet.';
    }

}
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#vqSVD6TQp)

---

#### Warning/Note

- You **can not** try to instantiate the parent (`abstract`) class:

> Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated
>   <sup>[*Source*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)</sup>

---

### Also...

This, in no way is how you should be calling/doing what you're trying to do. If you could tell us what task you're trying to achieve by doing this, we can help you further. Otherwise you'll constantly be writing code that isn't intended to work, only doing so due to *"work arounds"*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $this to access child methods

```
   Class a{
    function call_child_method(){
        if(method_exists($this, 'myFunction')){
            $this->myFunction();
        }
    }
}
Class b extends a{
    function myFunction(){
        echo 'Here is myFunction';
    }
}
$test = new b();
$test->call_child_method();
```

you will get output "Here is myFunction".

Comment: doesn't work and i can't get access to myFunction from a class

Answer (score 0):

You should use [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) class here.

```
abstract class a{  // define abstract class a
    // parent class constructor
    function __construct(){        
        // some code here
    }

    function test(){      
      $this->myFunction();
    }

    // define abstract method myFunction
    abstract function myFunction();
}

class b extends a{
    // child class constructor calls parent class constructor
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }

    // this method will be called
    function myFunction(){
        echo 'Here is myFunction';
    }
}

$b = new b; // create object of child class
$b->test();
```