# Calling a child class function if not exist in parent class

Tags: php, class

I have a code like following ---

```
class CartItem{
    var $v;
    function __construct(){
        $this->f();
    }
    function f(){
         echo 'In parent';
    }
}

class m extends CartItem{
    function f(){
        echo 'In child';
    }
}

new m();
```

Now when creating instance of m()... it doesn't have any constructor, so it is calling parent classes constructor. Now inside that a function f is called.

What I want is - 
if class m() have defined function f()... is should call it instead of parent class's function f().

But anyway it is calling parent classes function, as it was called from parent's constructor, irrespective of child class/ context :(

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944827/php-how-to-call-function-of-a-child-class-from-parent-class

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me

Comment: `protected function f` can be called in constructor of `CartItem` when `m` is instantiated.

Comment: @modsfabio, not a duplicate, instead a reverse scenario

Comment: @TusharSharma, how mate ? I am looking for such a thing

Comment: @Alice I mistakenly commented, I think. I was just about to confirm this behavior.

Comment: @Alice `$this->f()`, when `m` is instantiated. Instantiating `CartItem` won't work.

Comment: @TusharSharma from cart item constructor I want to call function f().

Comment: @TusharSharma, mate check my answer. You will get a better picture of what I am up to.

Comment: @Alice `CartItem` has no knowledge of method `f()`, so it can be called in constructor of `CartItem` but only when an instance of sub class is being made, and the sub class has a method `f()` with `protected` or higher visibility.

Comment: @TusharSharma, Got you, thanks

Comment: The updated code works as expected in all versions of PHP 5 and PHP 7. Check for yourself: https://3v4l.org/2Afed

Answer (score 1):

You want to call in `__construct()` a method that is not defined in the class. This is a sign that the `CartItem` class is an abstract concept and you don't intend to instantiate it (because an instance of `CartItem` probably doesn't contain enough information or behaviour for your project).

An abstract concept is implemented using an [abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) that defines as much as it can and defines abstract methods to be implemented in the concrete classes that extend it. The method `f()` is such a method that cannot be defined in the abstract concept and has to be defined in each class that extend it:

```
abstract class CartItem
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->f();
    }

    abstract protected function f();
}

class m extends CartItem
{
    protected function f()
    {
        // Implement behaviour specific to this class
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just done that now :) thanks anyways.
But another level of complexity, I don't want it to be abstract, if child class defines it then take child class's function or take it from parent itself

Comment: I don't get you. You can define the method in the base class and redefine it in the child classes when needed. `$this->f()` always calls the correct implementation (the one of the child class, if exists, the one of the base class otherwise). If you don't define the method `f()` in the base class then the correct implementation is to make it abstract because it cannot be instantiated anyway. You can leave `f()` undefined in the base class (and not make the class abstract) and use [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) before calling it but this is a hack.

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Just a curiosity: is `__construct()` called? The declaration `var $v;` is PHP 4 syntax. PHP 5 [uses the PHP 4 object model when it encounters `var`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) in a class declaration. But PHP 4 doesn't care about `__construct()`; it is not a constructor but a regular function in PHP 4. Read more about [PHP classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and get rid of `var`. I hope you are not using PHP 4, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really interesting question.

so, as I understand it, you're asking (**if this isnt right please say**):

> can you call a function of a class that's extending a parent?

yes, you can... sort of, if the method in the child is static.

Take this example (Ive not used it in the constructor for simplicity of example, but it will work there too):

```
class ClassA {

    public function testMeAsWell() {
        return ClassB::testMe();
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

    static function testMe() {
        return 'do something';
    }
}

$child = new ClassB();
echo $child->testMe();

// outputs 'do something'


$parent = new ClassA();
echo $parent->testMeAsWell();

// also outputs 'do something'
```

the reason this works needs more research, but as a guess I would say that because PHP is compiled, it will know about both classes at run-time and therefore will be able to figure out what we wanted it to do.

So, further on, you want to use variables.  Yes you can, but they would have to be static as well.

[working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/317037d5fa33d981c6b8a332126e0c120f58f5a8)

Comment: You have got, exactly what i am trying to do, but if I definew that static that means I will not be able to any class property :(

Comment: A static method is just global function with a funky name.

Comment: @Alice if you cant have a static, then no you cant do it.