# Calling Sub Class Method On Parent PHP Class

Tags: php, class, parent-child, extends

I have 2 PHP class that related each other, rather than using `__construct`, I tryin to using extends to combine these 2 class. But why sub class method cant called from parent class? There's no either result or error displayed but warning about reach memory limit.

here my example code:

```php
<?php
class Me
{

    public $you;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->you = new You;
    }

    public function Hi()
    {
        return 'Hi You';
    }

    public function WhatYouSaid()
    {
        return $this->you->Me();
    }

}

class You extends Me
{

    public function Me()
    {
        return 'Yes Me';
    }
}

$talk = new You;
print_r($talk->WhatYouSaid());
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/3d84d

I received error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xx bytes)

Based on @Nigel Ren answer i found solution here another example:

```
<?php
 class DataValidate {

    public $data;   

  public function __construct() {
     $this->data = new Data;
  }

public  function inputValidate($newData)
    {
        // verifying
        if ($this->data->get_data($newData['Identifier'], 'nameId'))
        {
            return false; // alredy exists
        }
        return $newData;
    }
    
}




class Data {

    public $db; 
    public $validate;

  public function __construct() {
     $this->db = new Database;
     $this->validate = new DataValidate; 
  } 

public  function get_data($identifier, $col)
        {
            return $this->db->select($identifier, $col='*');
        }
        
public  function inputValidate($newData)
{
    
    return $this->validate->inputValidate($newData);
}
}



$data = new Data;
print_r($data->inputValidate($some_id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you create a new object or type `You`, this calls the constructor in `Me`.  This then creates a new object of type `You`, this calls the constructor in `Me` ...

So you quickly run out of memory as it's creating loads of new objects.

There is also a case of having a different method name, I have assumed that you meant to have the same name for the 2 output methods.  You wouldn't normally introduce a new method in a sub class.

So this code just calls the method on the current object rather than creating a new object to use...

```
class Me {
    public  function Hi()
    {
        return 'Hi You';
    }

    public  function WhatYouSaid()
    {
        return $this->Hi();
    }   
    
}

class You extends Me{

    public  function Hi()
    {
        return 'Yes Me';
    }
}

$talk = new You;
print_r($talk->WhatYouSaid());
```

Edit:
If you just want to make the idea of calling a method from another class, then using `extend` doesn't help you at all.  It just needs to be a class which has a `public` method to allow you to call.

Then you create an instance of `Me` rather than `You` and make the call...

```
class Me
{
    public $you;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->you = new You;
    }

    public function Hi()
    {
        return 'Hi You';
    }

    public function WhatYouSaid()
    {
        return $this->you->Me();
    }
}

class You
{
    public function Me()
    {
        return 'Yes Me';
    }
}

$talk = new Me;
print_r($talk->WhatYouSaid());
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it make sense for the error displayed.

Actually the method inside ```You``` is needed. Maybe another example:

1. Class ```Data```, method ```add_data```, ```get_data```
2. Class ```DataValidation``` method ```input_validate```

Class ```Data``` is sub of ```DataValidation```, and ```input_validate``` need method ```get_data``` from sub class ```Data``` to verifying purpose / check if unique value already exists.

Should I need to rewrite method ```get_data``` into ```DataValidation``` ?

Comment: @RCahyo, it is just that you would normally define all of the methods in the base class.  Then in the derived classes you can override each one that needs specific functionality for the new class.  You can have new methods, but it then means that the base class needs to know about these - which makes a new dependency of the base class needs to know about any child class method.

Comment: Also thank you for your answer, thats solution my other question about same method name between two class

Comment: Ok I see, btw the validate method is came from ```helper``` it handling for many class Data, but I'm try'in to move into each class.

```someValidate($data, table, $action);``` (form helper)

it can called in every class

Comment: @RCahyo, I've added a new example which may be helpful?

Comment: Yes the ```__construct``` is what i'm tryin first, but then i'm just thinking to combine all so when its needed only have to calling one instance

instead

```$data = new Data;
$validate = new DataValidate;```

just 

```$data=new Data;
if $data->validate($input):```  So in the example, ```WhatYouSaid``` also can defined in ```You```

Comment: And after i rethinking, its more expandable using ```__construct``` rather than ```extends```, especially if involving methods relation between some class (more than 2), since we cant have multiple ```extends``` like  ```class You extends me, they, our``` 
 right?.

Comment: I have added new example based on your solution, thank you for your help @Nigel Ren

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that, each time  you try to create a **Me** object, it instantiate a **You** object (as you set in **Me**'s constructor).

As **You** extend **Me**, when you instantiate a **You** object, it starts by executing the code in **Me**'s constructor, so you go into a non-stop loop. Then you run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, thats make sense, but I'm still facing problem about how to using method from sub class into parent class

Comment: I reaally don't know why you're trying to do that. You probably better to redefine your workflow. This normally must not happened.
Whatever, if you really to do this, you can see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944930/11599770